# 'Too large to JOIN' error when I'm not using JOIN

Tags: google-bigquery

```
select 
CASE 
    WHEN .....
    ELSE .....
END AS carrier,
count(vehicle_id) as cnt
from test.vehicle_info 
WHERE vehicle_id NOT IN(select hardware_id 
                        from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(test.gps32_,DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -6,     'DAY'),DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
group by carrier
order by cnt
```

And  I got this error:

```
Query Failed
Error: Table too large for JOIN. Consider using JOIN EACH. For more details, please see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#joins
Job ID: red-road-574:job_e2o6sBjO9Dt5QrU_cRM2VHSRTso
```

What was the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: I would guess that `WHERE ... NOT IN (SELECT ...)` is getting transformed into a `LEFT JOIN` + an `IS NULL` condition behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hobbs's guess above is correct. SEMIJOIN (using `WHERE ... IN ...`) and ANTIJOIN (using `WHERE ... NOT IN ...`) are implemented as JOIN operations. The way to work around these restrictions is to rewrite as a join yourself, using join EACH. That is:

```
select 
CASE 
    WHEN .....
    ELSE .....
END AS carrier,
count(vi.vehicle_id) as cnt
from test.vehicle_info vi
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH (select hardware_id FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(...)) hi
ON vi.vechicle_id = hi.hardware_id
WHERE hi.hardware_id is NULL
group by carrier
order by cnt
```