# "Table too large for JOIN. Consider using JOIN EACH" but there are no joins

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I am getting an error from BigQuery stating "Table too large for JOIN. Consider using JOIN EACH", but there aren't any explicit joins in the SQL statement.  I have looked at another similar question, but I don't understand specifically how the answer they give relates to the problem I'm having.

['Too large to JOIN' error when I'm not using JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530188/too-large-to-join-error-when-im-not-using-join)

Here is the SQL

```
SELECT
userId AS userId,
deviceId AS deviceId,
MAX(CASE WHEN event_parameters.Name = 'Result' THEN event_parameters.Value END) AS ResultValue,
MAX(CASE WHEN event_parameters.Name = 'Points' THEN event_parameters.Value END) AS _Points,
MAX(CASE WHEN event_parameters.Name = 'Time' THEN event_parameters.Value END) AS _Duration,
CASE WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_01_onboarding Finished') THEN 1 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_02_onboarding Finished') THEN 2 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_03_onboarding Finished') THEN 3 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_04_onboarding Finished') THEN 4 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_05 Finished') THEN 5 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_06 Finished') THEN 6 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_07 Finished') THEN 7 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_01 Finished') THEN 8 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_02 Finished') THEN 9 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_03 Finished') THEN 10 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_04 Finished') THEN 11 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_05 Finished') THEN 12 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_01 Finished') THEN 13 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_02 Finished') THEN 14 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_03 Finished') THEN 15 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_04 Finished') THEN 16 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_05 Finished') THEN 17 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_08 Finished') THEN 18 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_09 Finished') THEN 19 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_10 Finished') THEN 20 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_11 Finished') THEN 21 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_12 Finished') THEN 22 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_13 Finished') THEN 23 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_14 Finished') THEN 24 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_06 Finished') THEN 25 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_07 Finished') THEN 26 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_08 Finished') THEN 27 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_09 Finished') THEN 28 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_10 Finished') THEN 29 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_11 Finished') THEN 30 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_06 Finished') THEN 31 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_07 Finished') THEN 32 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_08 Finished') THEN 33 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_09 Finished') THEN 34 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_10 Finished') THEN 35 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_11 Finished') THEN 36 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_12 Finished') THEN 37 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_15 Finished') THEN 38 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_16 Finished') THEN 39 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_17 Finished') THEN 40 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_18 Finished') THEN 41 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_19 Finished') THEN 42 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_20 Finished') THEN 43 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setA_lvl_21 Finished') THEN 44 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_12 Finished') THEN 45 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_13 Finished') THEN 46 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_14 Finished') THEN 47 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_15 Finished') THEN 48 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_16 Finished') THEN 49 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_17 Finished') THEN 50 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setB_lvl_18 Finished') THEN 51 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_13 Finished') THEN 52 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_14 Finished') THEN 53 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_15 Finished') THEN 54 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_16 Finished') THEN 55 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_17 Finished') THEN 56 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_18 Finished') THEN 57 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_19 Finished') THEN 58 WHEN event_name IN ('Level setC_lvl_20 Finished') THEN 59 ELSE 60 END AS _level,
FROM
TABLE_QUERY([dbset:dbname], "table_id CONTAINS 'game_table1' or table_id CONTAINS 'game_table2'  or table_id CONTAINS 'game_table3'")
WHERE
event_name LIKE 'Level%Finished'
GROUP BY
userId,
deviceId
```

I suspect the problem is with the "CASE WHEN event_name IN", as the linked question indicated that WHERE IN is an implicit join, so I wonder if it is also the case here, or if the LIKE statement could also be part of the problem.

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 1):

This can sometimes happen with semi-join statements (queries that follow the pattern `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)`). You can always rewrite a semi-join as a JOIN, and that can often help, since you can use `JOIN EACH` (there is no `IN EACH` operator).

However, your query, while it has IN, is not a semi-join (which Mosha pointed out). As he requested, if you can share your job id, one of the BigQuery engineers can look into what happened.

Comment: But in the above query IN is not semi-join, so it is puzzling why the error about JOIN came up. What is the jobid for the failing query ?

Comment: @Jordan How does re-writing the query as a JOIN help me if the problem is that the JOIN operation is too big?

Comment: Good point, mosha, I saw the IN and just assumed it was a semijoin.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mosha and Jordan that we need the jobid so we can debug this issue further. It is not at all clear why the query you provided would have resulted in a join at all.

But, I'd like to mention on other issue here: you probably would get somewhat better performance by using a join to replace that long CASE statement. I'm confused first of all that you are using IN there rather than =. I think you'd get the same semantics if you made that switch.

Assuming that's true, it could be better for you to make a small dimension table which maps the "Level set*" strings to the integers so that you could join that back to your table.

Hope that makes sense.